# show save button when sortable jquery script triggered

Tags: php, jquery, html

i am newbie to jquery.

I have been working on an assignment to make sortable divs and save it to database. Fortunately i done it.

My Question is how to save that record to database when the `save order` button clicked not when i move each divs and the save button should be hidden till i moved any div.

**This is how it looks**
[image]

**This is how when i move any of div**
[image]

**This is my divs**

```
$item=array(

'<div class="ara001" id="item_0"><a href="job"><div><img src="image/Home/jobs.gif"/><div >Jobs</div></div></a></div>',

'<div class="ara001" id="item_1"><a href="job" ><div><img src="image/Home/friends.png"/><div >Friends</div></div></a></div>',

'<div class="ara001" id="item_2"><a href="job"><div><img src="image/Home/mails.png"/><div >Mails</div></div></a></div>',

'<div class="ara001" id="item_3"><a href="job"><div><img src="image/Home/libraries.png"/><div >Books</div></div></a></div>',

'<div class="ara001" id="item_4"><a href="job"><div><img src="image/Home/entertainments.png"/><div >Entertainments</div></div></a></div>',

'<div class="ara001" id="item_5"><a href="job"><div><img src="image/Home/musics.png"/><div >Musics</div></div></a></div>',

'<div class="ara001" id="item_6"><a href="job"><div><img src="image/Home/videos.png"/><div >Videos</div></div></a></div>',

'<div class="ara001" id="item_7"><a href="job"><div><img src="image/Home/markets.png"/><div >Markets</div></div></a></div>');

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT sort FROM users WHERE UserName = '$user_name'");
$order=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$order=explode (',', $order[0]);
foreach($order as $key=>$value){
    echo $item[$value];}
    ?>
</div>
```

**This is the sortable script**

```
<script>
        $('#ara003').sortable({
    update: function( event, ui ) {
    var postData = $(this).sortable('serialize');
    console.log(postData);

    $.post('module/sort-save.php', {users: postData}, function(o){
        console.log(o);

        },'json');
    }
});

</script>
```

**And Finally this is sort-save.php file**

```
<?php
//------------------------------------------------------------
// RESTRICT ACCESS TO PAGE
//------------------------------------------------------------
require_once('../authentication/web.config.php');
require_once(ROOT_PATH.'global.php');
$auth_roles = array('member','user','owner','superadmin','etc.'); // << add roles here
//$premium_on = 1; $premium_access_levels = array('1','2');// << add premium access levels here
require_once(ROOT_PATH.'modules/authorization/auth.php');
require_once(ROOT_PATH.'user/modules/accordion/homepage_data.php');

$list = $_POST['users'];
$output=array();
$list=parse_str($list, $output);
$save=implode(',', $output['item']);
echo $save;
$conn->query("UPDATE users SET sort = '$save' WHERE UserName = '$user_name'");
?>
```

Comment: Is there any kind of error displayed in browser's DevTools or in your page?

Comment: @bcesars there is no error and everything is working fine, just i want to process the saving process to database with save button, and that save button should be hidden till i move any of divs.